# Swift scoping issue

Tags: swift, parse-platform, scoping

I have an app that is pulling info from a parse.com database and passing it into an array. When I println() this array from inside the while loop, it prints fine. When I try to print it outside the while loop, it returns empty. Here is my code:

```
var players = [String]()
var total = [String]()

var addTotal:AnyObject!
var addTotalFinal:Int!

var addPlayers:AnyObject!
var addPlayersFinal:Array<Int>!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var test: AnyObject!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     Parse.setApplicationId("KZ758LUTQZQ9Kl69mBDkv7BNLGHyXeKmqtFf7GmO", clientKey: "lOK5rg7wKeTRXZGV7MZBlQ5PTpNlGO0mkgtLkLgH")

    var query = PFQuery(className:"runningTotal")
    query.whereKey("total", notEqualTo: 0)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
    {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil
        {

            var i = 0

            while i < objects.count
            {

            self.addTotal = objects[i]["total"]
            self.addTotalFinal = self.addTotal as Int

            self.addPlayers = objects[i]["players"]
            self.addPlayersFinal = self.addPlayers as Array

            self.players.append("\(self.addPlayersFinal)")
            self.total.append("\(self.addTotalFinal)")

                ++i
            }



        }
        else
        {

        }




    }

    navigationItem.title = "\(players)"



 }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return players.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text = "\(players[indexPath.row]) - \(total[indexPath.row])"

    return cell

}
```

The println() in the while statement returns

```
[[1, 11, 12, 24, 25]]
[2]

[[1, 11, 12, 24, 25], [1, 5, 24, 25, 31]]
[2, 4]

[[1, 11, 12, 24, 25], [1, 5, 24, 25, 31], [2, 12, 25, 15, 31]]
[2, 4, -1]

[[1, 11, 12, 24, 25], [1, 5, 24, 25, 31], [2, 12, 25, 15, 31], [24, 22, 25, 31, 20]]
[2, 4, -1, -6]

[[1, 11, 12, 24, 25], [1, 5, 24, 25, 31], [2, 12, 25, 15, 31], [24, 22, 25, 31, 20], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[2, 4, -1, -6, 5]

[[1, 11, 12, 24, 25], [1, 5, 24, 25, 31], [2, 12, 25, 15, 31], [24, 22, 25, 31, 20], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 10, 11, 2, 12]]
[2, 4, -1, -6, 5, 1]
```

This makes sense, as there are six iterations. However, if I print inside the viewDidLoad statement instead of inside the while statement, it returns
    [][]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "inside the `viewDidLoad statement`?

Comment: "The println() in the while statement" I see no `println()` _anyhwere_.

Comment: I mean putting it outside of the entire parse statement and just right before the closing bracket in the viewDidLoad statement

Comment: Show it _in your code_. No one can guess what you might be doing. No one should have to. Show what you _are_ doing.

Comment: Show _what_ you are printing and _where_ you are printing it. Show your real code.

Comment: Right now, it's in there as     navigationItem.title = "\(players)" which is just helping to show it to me easier. It's at the end of the viewDidLoad statement.

Comment: Okay, I understand, thanks. Let me write out the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not understood how threads / asynchronous execution works. Let's be simpler. This is pseudo-code:

```
func viewDidLoad {
    doStepOne() // you configure your query here
    doStepTwoWithAsynchBlock {
        doStepTwo() // your while loop is here
    }
    doStepThree() // your failing println is here
}
```

This executes in the order `doStepOne()`, `doStepThree()`, `doStepTwo()`. So if `doStepThree()` tries to get a value that `doStepTwo()` sets, it isn't ready yet.

The asynch block is something that *will* happen, some time in the future - *after* all your other code has finished, including the whole of the rest of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Gotcha. So how would I apply this to my current code?

Comment: It _is_ your current code. You are trying to fetch `self.players` before it has been given a value. That ain't gonna work!

Comment: Ah, I see. So just to clarify, to fix it what do I need to do to make sure it's not being fetched before it has been given a value?

Comment: If you are in `viewDidLoad`, the only place where it has been given a value is after the `while` loop but _inside_ the background block.

Comment: If you are outside `viewDidLoad`, then if a method is called later, `self.players` might be set and it might not. :) That's what you get for doing a background query. You don't know when it will finish.

Comment: Yep, I see now. So how do I make it so that the values in that array are accessible outside the background block (ie. in the tableview functions)? Thanks again for all your help up to this point

Comment: Here's the thing. The values _will_ be available eventually. So you write your table functions to work whether the values are there are not; if there is nothing yet, just create a zero-row table.

Comment: Then, inside the background block, but after the while loop, you step out to the main thread and call the table's `reloadData` so that the table functions are called _again_. This time, there's data!

Comment: It might help you to read the chapter in my book about threads: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you so much... you have no clue how much you have helped me not only with the actual problem, but also understanding asynchronous methods. Thanks a ton.

Comment: It's the understanding that I am most concerned about! :) This is a concept of major importance so if you've grasped it you've made a major step forward here.

Comment: For sure... This definitely gives me a better grasp for the future.