# I need to call an Objective C method from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have this interface in Objective C that I am trying to call from Swift and it does not seem fall into the completion code.  Not sure what I am missing!

```
@interface WPLogin : NSObject

/*!
 * @brief Logs into the application returning success or failure with an error     object.
 * If login is successful the credential is automatically stored
 *
 * @param serverURLString   Address to login to
 * @param username  Username to login with
 * @param password  Password for user
 * @param completion Completion block to be called after attempting login
 */
- (void)loginToURL:(NSString *)serverURLString
      withUsername:(NSString *)username
              password:(NSString *)password
        completion:(void (^)(WPLoginStatus success, NSError * error))completion;

@end
```

the calling function from Swift looks like this...

```
    var uid = "test"
    var pwd = "test"
    var url = "http://www.google.com"
    var loginAuth = WPLogin();

        loginAuth.loginToURL(url, withUsername: uid, password: pwd, completion: { (status:WPLoginStatus, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            println("Inside Login")
    })
```

bridging file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WPLogin.h"
```

version that works in Objective C

```
if (!self.login) {
    self.login = [WPLogin new];
}

[self.login loginToURL:url
                       withUsername:uid
                           password:pwd
                         completion:^(WPLoginStatus status, NSError *error) {
                                NSLog(@"complete");
                          }];
```

Comment: Is #import "WPLogin.h" in your bridging header (if you don't have a bridging header you'll need one).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that.  I do have it and it is listed.  Code completion shows up and project compiles.  There aren't any run time errors either.  Just hits that line and keeps on going.  Never falls into the completion code to println()

Comment: It must be the case that the Objective-C method is not calling the completion method. The call looks fine.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  It works from Objective C but was trying to convert to Swift and can't get that to run.

Comment: "hits that line and keeps on going" correct, because the completion code is asynchronous

Comment: Show the objective c version that works, please.

Comment: Updated with Objective C

Comment: The bridging header does not need to include Foundation or UIKit in it. But, given that it's compiling, that's not the problem. It's more likely your use of local variable, as Matt discusses below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your Swift version the WPLogin object is a *local variable* (`var loginAuth`). Therefore it dies before it has a chance to *do* anything. Make it a *property*, as in your Objective-C version (`self.login`):

```
class MyClass {
    var login : WPLogin = WPLogin()
    func myMethod () {
        var uid = "test"
        var pwd = "test"
        var url = "http://www.google.com"
        self.login.loginToURL(url, withUsername: uid, password: pwd, completion: { 
            (status:WPLoginStatus, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            println("Inside Login")
        })
    }
}
```

This object needs to take action *over time* - going out on the Internet, logging in, calling your completion handler - and it cannot do that if it dies instantly, as it does in your Swift code. It must *persist* over significant time.

Comment: On the lifetime of objects assigned to different kinds of variables, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime

Comment: Also it appears from your comments that you may need to learn what "asynchronous" means in general. See my discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27053243/341994